# Spark Dataframe Array of Struct

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have a column in a dataframe that is an array [always of a single item], that looks like this:

```
root
 |-- emdaNo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- _value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

I can't for the life of me work out how to get the _value from it, in to a string...

Assuming x is the dataframe, i've tried:

```
x.select($"arrayName._value") // Yields ["myStringHere"]
```

and

```
x.select($"arrayName[0]._value") // Errors
```

How do i get a nice string of the value held in `_value` out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case class Element(_value: String, id: String)
val df = Seq(Array(Element("foo", "bar"))).toDF("emdaNo")
df.select(element_at($"emdaNo._value", 1) as "_value").show()
```

Output:

```
+------+
|_value|
+------+
|   foo|
+------+
```

Alternatively (and before Spark 2.4)

```
df.select($"emdaNo._value"(0))
```

or

```
df.select($"emdaNo._value".getItem(0))
```

Comment: thanks, interesting that you mention before spark 2.4 ... But that syntax looks much more readable than element_at

Comment: Agreed, the latter ones are arguably more readable for programmers with Scala/Java etc.. background. Function `element_at` was introduced in Spark 2.4 and perhaps it looks more familiar to people with strong SQL background where indexing starts from 1.